# How can I reference an Excel cell value as an HTML image source in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a macro that sends out an email template and inserts a picture at the top.

```
.HTMLBody = "<img src = 'C:\users\myIDnumber\desktop\logo.jpg'>"
```

I want to let a user enter their user ID in a cell, concatenating that into the file path into another cell, then referencing that cell as the file path.

I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax, help please?

Comment: `Sheet.Range("A1").Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a macro intended for different user to use on their own workstation, you could try:

```
.HTMLBody = "<img src = 'C:\users\" & Environ("username") & "\desktop\logo.jpg'>"
```

Here's a link for Environ's usage:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264486%28v=office.15%29.aspx

otherwise you can just use below:

```
dim user_id

user_id = sheet(1).cell("A1").value ' assuming it's Cell A1 in sheet 1
.HTMLBody = "<img src = 'C:\users\" & user_id & "\desktop\logo.jpg'>"
```